# Print TIF files with ghostscript in silent mode

Tags: printing, ghostscript

Is it possible to print tif files directly to a network printer without print dialog? I tried using the below code.

`<?php exec('gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="%printer%\\<ip_address>\Printer_name" tifFile.tif'); ?>`

Please help me to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript doesn't read TIFF files, so this isn't possible anyway, silent or not.

The mswinpr2 device, as far as I know, only works for printers which are local to the machine. This is because it uses the printer driver on the local PC, if you don't have a printer driver Ghostscript can't use it.

If you do have a printer driver then make a local printer which uses it (eg have the printer on FILE: or whatever magic is required for a network printer), and print to that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @KenS. Is there any other way to print the tif files to a network printer without print dialog

Comment: You can write a PostScript program whcih reads TIFF files, and submit that to Ghostscript using the mswinpr2 device. That doesn't get past the fact that you are using a network printer. I don't know of anythign which will do that for you. In fact its hard to see how anything could in the general case, it would need to know what Page Description Language the printer required and be prepared to reformulate the image data into whatever suited the printer. That's what printer drivers are for......

Comment: Ok.. At last I used pstools to print the files.